# Simple logging per public string?

Tags: java, android, logging

I do simple logging by adding strings during runtime to `public static String log = ""` in one class. The `log` is called via button to inflate `AlertDialog`.

Is there an even simpler way and can this lead to faulty behavior?

**Yes I am aware of LogCat** and also do not want to log to external file on the device.

Adding during runtime happens e.g. per

```
log = log + "\n>>another entry";
```

I am also under the maximum allowed string length to avoid problems:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    //save only last entries
    if (log.length() > 200000) log = log.substring(log.length() - 200000); 
    super.onStop(); //go on in super method
}
```

Comment: The way you do logging is already simple enough, except the fact that it isn't quite logging whose main purpose is to get info on how you app behaves at runtime. So, by "cutting off old log entries" you actually loose the info. Why not use a regular logging approach (with filters, if needed)?

Comment: Filters is a good idea. I used the string method to only get info I stored inside the code sections and see where the app is on runtime. I think youre right with its not quite logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using a String is as simple as it can get. Also what I do above is not quite logging, but it does help to see if code-sections were called or not, in which the strings are located.
e.g. to check whether a background service did call `onDestroy()` after the last client `unbind()` from it. Sure, `Log.e` could be used in debug, but not after installing the release elsewhere, I guess. 
The `AlertDialog` with the logged strings simply gives me some feedback on whats going on in the background.